# Get administrator rights in Windows XP

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I get administrator rights on Windows XP if im only user?. I know there is batch script for it but I can not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no batch script for it. You cannot.

You can Shift + Right Click and choose Run As another user, enter Admin name and password. In Vista and later this elevates, in XP and earlier you choose another user.